# Force all FMP Web to https

Tags: filemaker

Freshly installed FMP 14 Server, with valid SSL cert.

I'd like to know how force or redirect all web traffic to use https permanently on my server.

Thanks in advance!

Dan

Comment: Supporting this in the admin console would be a good feature request.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured this out.

Add the following to `/Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

Restart server